Missing bluetooth on Device Manager
The button bluetooth in my computer missed and I still don't see bluetooth on Device Manager.
Bluetooth Support Sevice in Service: Automatic
My computer configuration:
Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 19045)
System Manufactuer: Dell Inc
System Model: Latitude E5440
BIOS: BIOS date: 06/13/19 01:02:50 Ver: A24.00
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4010U CPU @ 1.70Ghz (4CPUs), $\approx$ 1.7GHz
Memory: 4096MB
DirectX Version: DirectX 12
I tried installing Intel Driver Bluetooth for Win10 but it still missed (I restarted my computer). I tried some solutions on Youtube but it not work.
Can someone give me a solution ?
Thanks a lot ?
